# How to add day to date in yii2?

Tags: date, datepicker, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, auto-value

how to add day to date yii2? when i enter checkin and hari, then value in checkout = checkin+hari.
can you help me?
thanks.

This is my code in form yii2, if date picker tanggal_masuk anda field jumlah_hari enter the data, then date picker = tanggal_masuk+jumlah_hari

```html
    <?= DatePicker::widget([
            'model' => $model,
            'attribute' => 'TANGGAL_MASUK',
            'template' => '{addon}{input}',
                'clientOptions' => [
                    'autoclose' => true,
                    'format' => 'dd-M-yy',
                    'startDate' => date('d-M-y'),
                    'prepend' => '<i class="icon-calendar"></i>'
                ]
        ]);?>

        <?php $data = 
         ['1' => '1 Malam',
         '2' => '2 Malam',
         '3' => '3 Malam',
         '4' => '4 Malam',
         '5' => '5 Malam',
         '6' => '6 Malam',
         '7' => '7 Malam',
         '8' => '8 Malam',
         '9' => '9 Malam',
         '10' => '10 Malam',
         '11' => '11 Malam',
         '12' => '12 Malam',
         '13' => '13 Malam',
         '14' => '14 Malam',
         '15' => '15 Malam']; ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'JUMLAH_HARI')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                'data' => $data,
                'language' => 'en',
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Hari'],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true
                ],
            ]); ?>
          
        <font size="2"><b>Check-Out</b></font>
        <?= DatePicker::widget([
            'model' => $model,
            'attribute' => 'TANGGAL_KELUAR',
            'template' => '{addon}{input}',
                'clientOptions' => [
                    'autoclose' => true,
                    'format' => 'dd-M-yy',
                    'startDate' => date('d-M-y'),
                    'prepend' => '<i class="icon-calendar"></i>'
                ]
        ]);?>
```

[this is my view in form yii2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXv12.png)

Comment: Do you need exactly in that format?

Comment: No, the most important is output of checkout date @EdvinTenovimas

Comment: In that case...

Comment: thank you so much @EdvinTenovimas

Comment: Oke @EdvinTenovimas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widget settings:

```
DatePicker::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'TANGGAL_MASUK',
    'template' => '{addon}{input}',
        'clientOptions' => [
            'autoclose' => true,
            'format' => 'yyyy-m-d',
            'startDate' => date('d-M-y'),
            'prepend' => '<i class="icon-calendar"></i>'
        ]
    ]);
```

The difference is this: `'format' => 'yyyy-m-d',` (changed format).

Now we retrieve value from this plugin. Let's say, we get this value from `Yii::$app->request->post()['Model']['TANGGAL_MASUK']`:

```
// Assigned to $time for easier access and converted to UNIX timestamp with strtotime()
$time = strtotime(Yii::$app->request->post()['Model']['TANGGAL_MASUK']);

// Let's calculate the value by adding the value of 2 days (in seconds)
$newTime = $time + 2 * 60 * 60 * 24;

// Let's convert back to your desired format (like: 29-Nov-16)
$newDate = date('y-M-d', $newTime);
```

Now we have `$newDate` variable that contains with added 2 days. Note that if you want to be able to use (add/substract or insert into DB), you'll have to change the format or use UNIX timestamp.